# Is it possible to get data of some form fields separately by clicking on a button in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, antd

I have a form with several fields I need to get values of some fields and save them in a state by clicking on a button and then sent all form field data to server by clicking on submit button. Is there any way to do it in react?

Here is an example code:

In this example user can add several account information by clicking on "Add account info" button I need to collect values of "Account Information" part of form in an array like this:

```
"accountInfo": [
    {
      "email": "",
      "securityQuestion": ,
      "securityAnswer": ""
    }
  ]
```

Finally by clicking on submit button all form values (including several account info) should be send to server.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { Form, Button } from 'antd'
import FormBuilder from 'antd-form-builder'

export default () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  const handleFinish = useCallback(values => {
    console.log('Submit: ', values)
  })
  const meta1 = [
    { key: 'name.first', label: 'First Name', required: true },
    { key: 'name.last', label: 'Last Name', required: true },
    { key: 'dob', label: 'Date of Birth', widget: 'date-picker' },
  ]
  const meta2 = [
    {
      key: 'email',
      label: 'Email',
      rules: [{ type: 'email', message: 'Invalid email' }],
    },
    {
      key: 'security',
      label: 'Security Question',
      widget: 'select',
      placeholder: 'Select a question...',
      options: [{label: "What's your pet's name?", value: 1 }, {label: 'Your nick name?', value:2}],
    },
    { key: 'answer', label: 'Security Answer' },
  ]
  const meta3 = {
    fields: [
      { key: 'address', label: 'Address' },
      { key: 'city', label: 'City' },
      { key: 'phone', label: 'phone' },
    ],
  }

  return (
    <Form layout="horizontal" form={form} onFinish={handleFinish} style={{ width: '500px' }}>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <FormBuilder form={form} meta={meta1} />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>
        <FormBuilder form={form} meta={meta2} />
        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 16, offset: 8 }}>
        <Button type="primary">
          Add account info
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Infomation</legend>
        <FormBuilder form={form} meta={meta3} />
      </fieldset>
      <Form.Item className="form-footer" wrapperCol={{ span: 16, offset: 8 }}>
        <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Can you share an example so we can see the field structure?

Comment: I've added an example code to my question @darshilsakhiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two keys in antd FormInstance interface you might be interested in.

1. `getFieldsValue` to get whole values of your form by a set of field
   names.
2. `getFieldValue` to get the value by the field name.

However you can get those values and do whatever you want with them by button with *htmlType="submit"*:

```
<Button form="myForm" htmlType="submit"> my btn </Button>
```

To make this button work do not forget to assign some function to the key *onFinish* of your form:

```
<Form
   onFinish={(formData) => console.log(formData)}
   id="myForm"
   // ... your other properties
>
   ...
</Form>
```

Comment: I see you have updated your question with your code, so why you don't want to build your value _accountInfo_ in `handleFinish` function?